# Raspberry Pi 2 Model B+ odd booting issue

Tags: pi-2

I ran into an odd issue with my Raspberry Pi and was hoping someone could help me point in a right direction here.

I have a Model B Raspberry Pi successfully running latest Raspbian (downloaded from Raspberry Pi) for couple months now.

But today when I powered my board, I realized the power LED was not coming on and the ACT led is solid green (does not blink)

Troubleshooting I have done:

1. Checked the output of power cable and I was able to read 5v on my pins.
2. I do realize my fuse pin's voltage was low (4.1v) .
3. I have tested my same SD Card and the power cable with a older model Raspberry Pi and it boots up fine.

I cannot find this combination (red LED off and green LED solid on) on the troubleshooting documents, so I am not sure where the problem lies. Is it that the board has gone bad or there is something possibly wrong with the SD Card?

Any help is appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: *"this combination (red led off and green led solid on)"* -> Shame I did not notice this Q when it was first posted.  Red and green on is normal for the 2 without a card, it is different from other models in this sense.  If it does that with a card, it may just mean the card is improperly formatted or seriously corrupted.

Answer (score 1):

I blew up my first RPi Model 2 with surging power problems and it shows red AND green permanently on with or without an SD card.
Query: 1) You do not state whether the RPi boots at all? Do you have a monitor attached to see if there is any life at all? A partial boot can sometimes give you a lot of information BUT cannot be viewed via SSL.
Suggest: That it is a power issue 1)too low input voltage to the USB and the RPi will not work. From my experience anything below 4.7 or 4.8 is too low. 2) If your RPi is burnt I suggest you read this 
http://www.petervis.com/Raspberry_PI/dead-raspberry-pi/dead-raspberry-pi.html

good luck, ianm

Comment: Thanks cheetah7. I forgot to mention that I don't see any thing on my monitor, so that made me think the pi isn't coming on but then I saw the ACT led staying on, so I was confused.

Comment: Take the SDCard out, remove any USB devices. Power on - if any parts of your RPi get too hot to touch very quickly then it's dead - you're looking at the $35 fix for it.

Comment: The model two will show red and green without a card without having been blown up, ie., that's not a symptom of a problem.  It is different from other models though.  Red and green *with* a card may be either physical damage or an improperly formatted card.